# how to use both word2vec and RNN for NLP together?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, recurrent-neural-network

I recently studied and understood how `word2vec` works, it is responsible to convert words into numerical form so when we plot them or put them in the world space they will be spread and reveal the relationship between every word and the other.

my question here, I found also `RNNs` and suddenly I became confused. Is `word2vec` an alternative to `RNNs` or I can use `word2vec` to transfer the words to numeric form and then use them on `RNNs` ?

I mean both of them predict the next word, so I want to know if they are the different approaches for the same problem or I can use them both together ?

**NOTE:** I finished computer vision and started in NLP so please don't judge my question I am just starting, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You did not understood the meaning of `word2vec` clearly. `word2vec` is a representation of words in a multi-dimensional space while `RNN` is an algorithm like `Linear Regression` or `random forest` or `logistic regression`. `word2vec` do NOT predicts the next words. Here is a small explanation of `word2vec`:

Take three words: `apple`,`orange` and `car`. Suppose they are represented in `word2vec` as:

`apple = [0.01, 0.04 ...]` `orange = [0.02, 0.06 ...]` `car = [0.03, 0.09 ...]`

Now you know `apple` and `orange` are similar to each other while `car` is not. So if you will take the dot product of `apple` and `orange`, the result value will be close to `1`, say it's `0.85` but if you take the dot product of `apple` and `car`, the result will be far from `1` say it's `0.25`. This is the concept of `word2vec`. It gives you a vector representation of words in a numerical form such that similar words are kept near to each other in the graph.

Now for `RNN`, as I said, it's an algorithm. You will feed some numerical data to it and it'll give you some output. You need to learn `RNN` in detail from some online tutorial.

To answer your question about how to use them together, `RNN` takes numerical inputs. It can't take English words directly. So we need to convert all words into some kind of numerical form. This is where `word2vec` comes into picture. You take each word, get it's numerical representation from `word2vec` (like I showed above for `apple`, `orange` and `car`) and then feed it to the `RNN`.

This is just a simple overview and it's not possible to explain everything here. If you really want to learn more then I would strongly suggest you to take [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/nlp-sequence-models/) course. Everything from `word2vec` to `RNN` is explained beautifully there. It would be even better if you complete the whole specialisation there instead of completing only this course.